Why does the presence of bound variables make enumerating the terms of lambda calculus “unsolveable with generating functions/analytic combinatorics?”

…amazingly very little is known about combinatorial aspects of λ-terms, probably because of the intrinsic difficulty of the combinatorial structure of lambda calculus due to the presence of bound variables… Perhaps the reason for this ignorance lies in the surprising form of the recurrences. Indeed, due to the presence of bound variables, the recurrence does not work in the way mathematicians expect and are used to. The induction lies on two variables, one decreasing (the size), the other increasing (the number of free variables). Thus none of the methods used in the reference book of Flajolet and Sedgewick [8] applies. Why is that? In what follows we compute the number of λ-terms (and of normal forms) of size n with at most m distinct free variables. Denoting the number of such terms by $T_{n,m}$, the formula for $T_{n,m}$ contains $T_{n−1,m+1}$ and this growth of m makes the formula averse to treatments by generating functions and classical analytic combinatorics. We notice that for a given n the expression for $T_{n,m}$ is a polynomial in m. These polynomials can be described inductively and their coefficients are given by recurrence formulas. These formulas are still complex, but can be used to compute the constant coefficients, which correspond to the numbers of closed λ-terms. For instance, the leading coefficients of the polynomials are the well known Catalan numbers which count binary trees.


For a given $n$, the formula for $T_{n,m}$ is a polynomial “in $m$”.

$m$ is the number of distinct variables. When they say “in $m$”, I assume they mean, “in the set of the $m$ variables”, right?

These polynomials can be described inductively and their coefficients are given by recurrence formulas.

I will see their formula later in the text, but for now am wondering, if the polynomials are defined “inductively”, isn’t that the same thing as being given by a “recurrence formula”? I suppose I always thought of induction as a kind of recursion. Perhaps that was a mistake. Is there a specific reason the polynomials are inductive, but the coefficients are recursive?

Could someone give me a short demonstration of why the presence of bound variables would make a recurrence “not work in the way mathematicians would expect”? Is that to say that recursion with free variables is easier since the variables are substituted with the expression of the recursion itself? Would a bound variable not just act like a constant?

Why does it say the induction is on decreasing size? Shouldn’t the induction be on increasing string length?

Why does the fact that they are doing induction over $m$ distinct variables cause the problem to not be solveable with “generating functions or analytic combinatorics”? The rate of growth is simply of a higher order than anything a generating function could express? I find that surprising and would like to see it proven why that is.


Thank you.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.2610.pdf
